# What does "this" point to in sub function of method?

Tags: javascript, this

I wrote a contrived script that illustrates what I don't understand:

```
var newObject = {}
newObject.testAttribute = "I'm newObject";
newObject.someMethod = function(){
    console.log(this.testAttribute);
    var sub_function = function(){

        console.log(this.testAttribute);   
    }
    sub_function();
}
newObject.someMethod();
```

In the sub_function, I expected "this" to refer to the object newObject because of closure, but the output on the console is

```
"I'm newObject"
undefined
```

Comment: My question was marked as a duplicate by Quentin, but it doesn't say what question I have duplicated.

Comment: I see it now.  Rather long thread.

Comment: And vague, whereas my question is very specific.

Comment: I would suggest to change your username and avatar, since it might be considered offensive.

Comment: OK.  I'm not sure how to do either of those things, but I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

`this` represents a context. Every function has its own context unless you directly specify it, e.g.

```
this.myfunction = function(){}
```

or

```
myfunction.bind(this)
```

you can learn more [here](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/)